# .htaccess на хостинге - странно работает ( редирект https + ЧПУ )

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, чпу

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^user([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^settings/?$ settings.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Сначала все работало нормально, потом решил прописать перенаправление на https, вроде всё заработало, но с некоторыми проблемами.

***Проблема 1: (UPD: Решено. Сначала надо редирект, а потом только ЧПУ)***
С ссылок типа http://site.ru/user1 перебрасывает на https://site.ru/profile.php?user=1, то есть без ЧПУ.

***Проблема 2: (UPD: решена, спасибо, причина в кэше браузера)***
 
Перепробовав различные варианты, в конце концов получилось так, что теперь даже убрав из .htaccess перенаправление, оно все равно остаётся! Теперь я даже не могу вернуть все как было.

Comment: Проблема 2: т.к. возвращается код 301 (Moved *Permanently*) браузер это запоминает и перенаправление остаётся. Нужно отчистить кэш браузера

Comment: 2 проблема понятна, спасибо. По 1 проблеме я ошибся, вообще любые ссылки с ЧПУ так ведут себя. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d и RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f убрал - не помогло.

Comment: @АндрейДиневич, сначала проверяйте на https и делайте редирект для него, а потом уже чпу.

Comment: @Visman Спасибо, сработало! Я просто запутался из-за кэширования, я еще до это так пробовал )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Проблема 1:** сначала нужно делать редирект на https, а потом ЧПУ. Проблема в том, что mod_rewrite сначала запоминает, что ему нужно обращаться к не-ЧПУ-адресу, а потом видит флаг `[R]` и перенаправляет на него. Если поставить внешнее перенаправление на первое место, то этой проблемы не будет

**Проблема 2:** т.к. возвращается код 301 (Moved **Permanently**) браузер это запоминает и перенаправление остаётся. Нужно отчистить кэш браузера